# Trying to list the students who are enrolled in the same class as the class which is scheduled

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to list the students who are only in that specific class in the list rather than having every single student. To do this, I have the following `ViewBag` in my Attendance Controller

```
var cscid = db.Class_Schedule.Select(a => a.ClassID);
        var classstudents = db.Students.Where(p => p.Enrollments.Select(o => o.ClassID).Equals(cscid));
        ViewBag.studentID = new SelectList(classstudents,"StudentID","Full_Name");
```

I am trying to show the students who are enrolled in the same class as the class_schedule class 
but I get the following exception:

```
System.NotSupportedException: 'Cannot compare elements of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]'. Only primitive types, enumeration types and entity types are supported.'
```

And this is my View;

```
        <p class="right">Student ID @Html.DropDownList("studentID", null, "--Select Student--", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, you want to find all the students that belong to this specific class schedule.

First you have to supply the class schedule ID;

```
// SUPPLY WHICH CLASS SCHEDULE WE'RE IN
int classScheduleId = 1; 

// find this class schedule
var classSchedule = db.Class_Schedule.FirstOrDefault(c=>c.ClassScheduleId == classScheduleId);
```

Once we've found the current class schedule, we want to find all the students that belong to that class schedule.

```
// Use .any to test if the list or properties inside the list suffice the condition
var classStudents = db.Students.Where(s=>s.Enrollments.Any(e=>e.Class.ClassSchedules.Any(c=>c.ClassScheduleId == classSchedule.ClassScheduleId))).ToList();
```

Comment: I think you have misunderstood the first part, as the class_schedule has as classID which is basically what class it is so is it "Kids MMA" or "Adults MMA" i would want the students who are enrolled on the "Kids MMA" or "Adults MMA to only show in the ViewBag List.

Comment: @IchigoKurosaki `var cscid = db.Class_Schedule.Select(a => a.ClassID);` will return a list-- so you want to identify all the students that belong to this list of Class IDs?

Comment: Yes so the students which go to the adult classes will only show in the ViewBag list

Comment: @IchigoKurosaki added new answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this one instead. We first have to save the class schedule Class IDs to an array. Then we check if the students are enrolled to any of those Class IDs.

```
// save to array
var cscid = db.Class_Schedule.Select(a => a.ClassID).ToArray();

// use linq logic similar to WHERE IN array
var classstudents = db.Students.Where(p => p.Enrollments.Any(o=>csid.Contains(o.ClassID)).ToList();
```